# C# MySql error: MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException

Tags: c#, mysql

I am trying do to a program that sends you a verification code to register, but everytime i try it there comes this error:

> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: "Authentication to host 'server' for user 'user' using method 'mysql_native_password' failed with message: Access denied for user 'user'@'p4fe986ad.dip0.t-ipconnect.de' (using password: YES)"

I searched for answers but i did not find some.
so i thought i could ask a question too.
Ah and yeah here is the code :D

```
Register r = new Register();
        confirmed_pass = r.confirmpw.Text;


        if (randomcode == code.Text.ToString())
        {
            
                string verbindungsdaten1 = "SERVER=server;" +
                                     "DATABASE=db;" +
                                     "UID=user;" +
                                     "PASSWORD=password;";

             MySqlConnection verbindung1 = new MySqlConnection(verbindungsdaten1);

                string command = "INSERT INTO Accounts VALUES ('" + text + "', '" + utils.hashPassword(confirmed_pass) + "', false);";
                MySqlCommand com = new MySqlCommand(command, verbindung1);
                verbindung1.Open();
                com.ExecuteNonQuery();
                verbindung1.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("Sucessfully registered Account!", "Sucess");
                MainWindow login = new MainWindow();
                login.Show();
                this.Close();

           
                

        }
```

The error comes here:

> verbindung1.Open();

Comment: Did you tried to enter your username and password without ';' ?

Comment: @Sajed what do you mean? i dont use ";"

Comment: @Dmitry i will try it! :D

Comment: @Dmitry it didnt helped

Comment: Just to be clear, you tried and verified all answers from the question @Dmitry linked to, in 5 minutes?

Comment: You have a bunch of other issues: You need `using` to dispose all the `MySql` objects. You should parameterize your SQL, otherwise you are open to SQL injection and syntax errors. Specify column names to insert into. Don't hardcode connection strings. There is a lack of error handling.

Comment: Almost certainly your username or password is incorrect in the connection string. Have you connected from another client to verify that you can connect with those credentials?